# Mongo UUID Type 03 instead of 04 from mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

MongoDB UUID conversion from Mongo Shell turns out be TYPE 03, legacy format. How do we get it to work with TYPE 04, binary format?

```
> db.foo.insert({"_id":1000,"key1":UUID("240003A09CEC456AB57B98FF8E0E45DB")})
  WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.foo.find({_id:1000})
  { "_id" : 1000, "key1" : BinData(3,"JAADoJzsRWq1e5j/jg5F2w==") }
> db.version()
  3.4.2
```

From Java code we are able to use bytebuffers and insert as type 04 binary uuid, sample : BinData(4,"XWCwWqIVTfiEkTx9Yl+2UQ==").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put the data directly into the `BinData()` function as type 4, by extracting the base64 encoding and supplying it:

```
var t = BinData(4, UUID("240003a09cec456ab57b98ff8e0e45db").base64())
BinData(4,"JAADoJzsRWq1e5j/jg5F2w==")
```

And then you still get the supplied value from hex:

```
t.hex()
240003a09cec456ab57b98ff8e0e45db
```

Or just supply directly to `HexData()`:

```
HexData(4,"240003a09cec456ab57b98ff8e0e45db")
BinData(4,"JAADoJzsRWq1e5j/jg5F2w==")
```

If you have data with hyphens in between then use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to reformat:

```
var str =  "240003A0-9CEC-456A-b57B-98FF8e0E45DB";
str.split('-').join("").toLowerCase();
"240003a09cec456ab57b98ff8e0e45db"
```

A JIRA ticket exists to make `UUID()` generate type 4 as default [SERVER-12835](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12835), but it is a low priority issue. For general usage your interactions should be "driver" based instead. But there are these methods to work with the shell.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just curiosity, any reason why UUID() function is still kept as old legacy format? Can an option type be added to say type 04.

Comment: @dilsingi It's always been that way, I somehow do not seen the shell changing. There probably is a JIRA ticket around, but as a "utility" it would not be a high priority. As noted, there is `HexData` from the shell as well as the demonstrated method to move data between different types. Main support is rather given to "driver" implementations, which for any industrial purpose, you should be using instead.

Comment: @dilsingi Added the JIRA Issue for reference. But as stated, it's low priority. Use the methods as shown when working from the shell.

Comment: Thank you once again. Noticed there were some data in the documents with "-" separator.  They ended up in error when using HexData db.foo.insert({"_id":1002,"key1":HexData(4,'AC1AAB22-0BF9-4127-BDC2-9C11398130AE')})
2017-07-01T19:10:41.286-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Invalid hex character in string : @(shell):1:34. Apologized, missed to notice them in my original script. Any tricks to convert them?

Comment: @dilsingi Even with the hyphens removed [that is not a valid value](http://guid.us/Test/GUID). You can strip hyphens with `.split()` and `.join()` JavaScript functions. But the data does need to be valid. That is not. If you have a new question the [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)