# Convert BinData type 3 data to type 4 in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Is there a written method for converting BinData with a subtype of 3 to BinData with a subtype of 4?

Basically I would like to convert all the UUIDs in our database to use the new format.

I assumed that there would be a script/method of doing this.

Thanks
Ian

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 possible ways that data is stored in a subtype 3 binary aka "legacy UUID". See https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/uuid.rst.

Generally speaking, you can read each document using your programming language, convert the value to subtype 4, then save the document back. A solution using MongoDB shell is given in [Mongo UUID Type 03 instead of 04 from mongo shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44866192/mongo-uuid-type-03-instead-of-04-from-mongo-shell) (as linked), but note that it would only be correct for 1/3 of the producers of subtype 3 binaries.

Depending on which programming language you use you may get different values for the output since input will be interpreted differently.

I haven't researched what methods the server provides for bulk-converting subtype 3 binaries. It's possible there aren't any because it doesn't know how to interpret the bytes in a subtype 3 binary due to there being 3 possible interpretations.